# Linking two phones/users together in Android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-signin

Hi I am designing an Android App using Android Studio for my class and one of the requirement is that the app should link two users together as "partners" so that they can receive notifications or messages from each other. I already have google sign in available but I don't know how to link two users together. Can someone point me in the right direction to get started? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking to create an app that can connect users wirelessly and then do whatever tasks you wish to do. Now I'm not going to give you the code or anything like that, but I'm going to point you in the right direction as you asked.

The Android Developers site is a good place to start: [Building Apps with Connectivity](http://developer.android.com/training/building-connectivity.html)

The first two categories are closely related to your type of question, and will give you the stepping stone you need to start developing an app that fits your purpose.

Anytime you have an actual issue with coding it, StackOverflow will have countless solutions I'm sure.